# Pull Requestの出し方について

Tags: git, github

GitHub初心者の質問です．

結構著名な組織がGitHubに公開しているツールがあります．antのbuild.xmlとそれから起動される数種類のターゲットに対応するXSLTスタイルシート、および共通のスタイルシートで構成されています．
このツールは（たぶん）２つの目的があり、１つにはXSLTスタイルシートによりメインの変換を行うこと、２つにはそのメインの変換が終わった後、その結果を利用して派生するであろう無数のサブの変換を行うことです．1つ目の変換結果はすでに確定しています．

私はこのリポジトリをfork⇒cloneして上記の２つ目の用途をローカルで試してみました．なのですが、

① そもそもbuild.xmlからして間違いがある．
② メインの変換は（結果が公開されて仕様になっているので）大丈夫だったのでしょうけれどもサブの変換はまともな結果を出してくれない．

という残念な結果になっています．仕事上どうしてもこのツールを使用する必要性があるため、ローカルで修正してテストしていますが、見てゆくとターゲット別のXSLTスタイルシートの側にも単純なコーディングミスやバグ、そして期待した結果を得ることができないコードが見つかりました．

issueを出しているのですが、メンテナーの方も忙しいらしく、そのやりとりだけでは埒が空きません．そこでPull Requestを出そうと考えたのですが、上記のように様々なレベルで修正しなければならない箇所があり、どのようにPull Requestを出したら良いのかがわかりません．

まずPull Requestを出すためのブランチを作る手順は「GitHub実践入門」（WEB+DB PRESS plus 技術評論社）を読んで理解できたつもりです．しかし上記のように修正点が多岐にわたる場合、は具体的にはどのような手順でブランチを作り、Pull Requestを出して行ったら良いのでしょうか？

たぶんスタイルシート以前のbuild.xmlの間違いから直してゆくようPull Requestを出す必要があると思うのですが、それ以降のスタイルシートの様々な箇所にわたる修正は、段階的にでないと解決できないように思えます．このような場合、順を追って１つづPull Requestが取り込まれるのを待ちながら出してゆくべきなのでしょうか？またブランチはPull Requestに一対一対応させないとダメなのでしょうか？

以上 お手数ですが回答の程よろしくお願いします．

Comment: 個人的にはまとめて出せば良いんじゃないかと思いますが、他の方の意見も聞いてみたいところです。すべての変更点が密接に結びついていればまとめて出すしか無い気もしますが、変更点はバグフィックス、機能変更、など、ある程度の粒度で単位分けできますか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます．
まず単純なbuild.xmlやコーディングのミスは１つにまとめられると思います．問題はそれからです．build.xmlのターゲット別にスタイルシートがあるのですが、全体の目標は本来可能であるべき変換元の記法を正常に処理できるようにするのが主眼です．このためには共通スタイルシートの修正と、ターゲット別のスタイルシートの両方の修正が必要になります．４つのターゲットがあるので、順に直しているのですがなかなか難航しています．とりあえず、共通スタイルシートの修正と、それに対応した４つのターゲット別のスタイルシートの修正（これは共通スタイルシートを直したために必要なだけの暫定）、と4つのターゲット別の個々の修正という単位分けはできそうです．この順番を踏めば、途中の個々のPull Requestでは完全な結果は得られなくとも最後まで行き着けば望まれる結果は得られると踏んでいます．
書いていて気が付きましたが、やはりこれは、Pull Requestを受け取る側の身になって考えなければいけないものですよね．全部まとめて出すとやはり相手方は混乱するし、テストしきれなくて却下される可能性があるような気がします．これが一番恐れていることです．（メインテナーは結構著名人で多忙なのです）

Comment: なるほど、突き詰めると メンテナーが望む形が一番いいでしょうね。issueでやり取りされてるということなので、修正の単位を分けて、それらの修正一覧を伝え、一部 もしくは全部の PullRequestを出す用意ができてることを相談してみてはどうでしょう。

Comment: コメントありがとうございました．
さっそく修正項目をもう一度整理して、Pull Requestの出し方をまとめてみます．

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(コメントの内容をまとめています)

メンテナーにマージしてもらいたい修正の内容を伝えて、メンテナーにどうマージ(PR) して行ったら良いかを聞く。